# using references inside a table

Tags: tables, bibliographies, miktex

I am trying to analyse my bibliography in a Tabular way, to obtain the following output:

[image]

for this, I use the following piece of code

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\begin{document}      

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
reference & Charactersitic 1 & Charactersitic 2 & Charactersitic 3 \\ 
\hline
\cite{X} & method xx & method xy & method xz \\ 
\hline
\cite{Y} & method yx & method yy & method yz \\ 
\hline
\cite{Z} & method zx & method zy & method zz \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{BibliographyTest}

\end{document}
```

The bibliography is in the followinf `BibliographyTest.bib` file as follows:

```
@ARTICLE{X,
AUTHOR = {X. Author},
TITLE = {Title 1},
JOURNAL = {Journal of X},
YEAR = {1961},
volume = {16},
pages = {8--37},
} 

@BOOK{Y,
AUTHOR = {Y. Author},
TITLE = {Title 2},
PUBLISHER = {Publicher of Y},
YEAR = {2004},
edition = {2nd Edition},
}

@BOOK{Z,
AUTHOR = {Z. Author},
TITLE = {Title 3},
PUBLISHER = {Publicher of Z},
YEAR = {2004},
edition = {2nd Edition},
}
```

**Compile -> Bibtex -> Compile** produces no errors, no warning, but also, **no output PDF file !**

Can anyone help please?

Comment: It compiles fine for me. Try deleting the `.aux` and `.bbl` files.

Comment: thanks, that worked. Now can I use the same *.bib file with a graphical tool such as Latable ? having more then 200 reference, will make thinks impossible  to trace !

Answer (score 2):

You must be looking at the wrong output file, or using your IDE in an incorrect way. I compiled your file from the command line, and obtained the following without any problem:[image]